# Is it possible to set the right margin to something other than 0 for a div element of class ="container-fluid"?

Tags: bootstrap-5

The following code gives me margin on the top and left but nothing on the right (end).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid m-2 bg-dark text-white">
  This is a test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`container-fluid` has `width: 100%;` which causes the issue. You can add `width: auto`, i.e, `w-auto` to solve the issue.

```html
<link 
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid m-2 bg-dark text-white w-auto">
  This is a test
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That solved the issue. But why would it allow the top and left margin to be set (shown) when width:100% and not right margin?

Comment: This is my understanding. `display:block` elements like `div` are better off with `width: auto`. `width: 100%` here makes the width `100% +16px` here. As a result overflow happens.